# object references an unsaved transient instance in Hibernate 4.3

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

This is not the usual situation, but I'm hoping someone can shed some light. This used to work in Hibernate 3, but I have recently upgraded which broke things.

I am using Hibernate 4.3.5 with an Oracle 11g database.

Assume a set of entity classes that looks like this (some code omitted for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table("MY_FILES")
public class MyFileInfo {

  private String fileId;
  private String name;
  private MyFileData myFileData;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                  generator = "fidSeq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "fidSeq",
                     sequenceName = "SQ_FILE_ID",
                     allocationSize = 10,
                     initialValue = 1)
  @Column(name="FILE_ID")
  public String getFileId() {
    return fileId;
  }

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "myFileInfo",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            optional = false,
            cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  public MyFileData getMyFileData() {
    if (myFileData == null) {
      myFileData = new MyFileData(this);
    }
    return myFileData;
  }

  // ... setters ... //
}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table("MY_FILES")
public class MyFileData {

  private String fileId;
  private MyFileInfo myFileInfo;
  private byte[] content;

  public MyFileData() {}
  public MyFileData(MyFileInfo myFileInfo) {
    setMyFileInfo(myFileInfo);
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "FILE_ID",
          insertable = false,
          updatable = false)
  public String getFileId() {
    return fileId;
  }

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "FILE_ID",
              referencedColumnName = "FILE_ID",
              insertable = false,
              updatable = false)
  public MyFileInfo getMyFileInfo()
  {
    return myFileInfo;
  }

  @Column(name = "FILE_CONTENTS",
          insertable = false)
  public byte[] getContent()
  {
    return content;
  }

  public setMyFileInfo(MyFileInfo myFileInfo) {
    this.myFileInfo = myFileInfo;
    fileId(myFileInfo.getId());
  }

  // ... other setters ... //
}
```

Note that the code here was written outside an IDE and was not tested or compiled. See flaws, let me know.

Alright, now I know that's strange since I'm mapping two entities to the same table. The whole purpose here is the ability to load `MyFileInfo` objects without getting the `FILE_CONTENTS` column, allowing a list of files without downloading potentially large files from the database. "Why not just use a native query or something like that," you ask? Well, the use of Hibernate is quite extensive and tightly coupled in this application, and catching all the places we load file contents unnecessarily would be nearly impossible.

With all that being said, I used to be able to write to the database in Hibernate 3.6.10 using a series of calls that looked like this:

```
final MyFileInfo info = new MyFileInfo();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
info.setMyFileData(new MyFileData(info));
session.saveOrUpdate(info);
session.flush();
session.refresh(info);
info.getMyFileData().setFileId(info.getId());
session.saveOrUpdate(info.getMyFileData());
```

It's all very complicated and kludgey-feeling, but it worked. Now I get the infamous `object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing` error, but I can't save the `MyFileInfo` object first--the flush/refresh would get the generated ID I need to set on the `MyFileData` object in order to be able to save it.

Any help here is greatly appreciated. Drop it in the comments if I need to supply more information! Thanks!

Comment: Edit made, thanks. And for #1, I would love to do that. But the environment doesn't allow it. #2: This works only on databases that support Lazy Column Fetching (i.e. - NOT Oracle) or bytecode instrumentation, which I have not looked into. I will update this if I go that route. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. Basically, since I had `insertable=false` on all properties of `MyFileData`, it never tried the insert. It didn't care that the object itself was still transient as far as Hibernate was concerned.

Comment: Because of `myFileData` having `optional=false` (this is what allows lazy initialization), waiting to call `setMyFileData()` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was much simpler than I expected. I was able to fix it by moving the persistence logic around and not touching the `@Entity` classes:

```
final MyFileInfo info = new MyFileInfo();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

// saveOrUpdate actually gets the id from Hibernate's sequence cache,
// which doesn't need a flush
session.saveOrUpdate(info);

// then I can set the ID where appropriate and save (update) the "new" entity
info.setMyFileData(new MyFileData(info));
info.getMyFileData().setFileId(info.getId());
session.saveOrUpdate(info.getMyFileData());

// the flush will save the MyFileInfo object and perform a no-
// consequence update on the MyFileData object.
session.flush();
session.refresh(info);
```